# Not able to Sync Local git (on AWS Ubuntu) with Remote (which is on BitBucket)

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, local

I am new to Git and hence struggling please help. I have an AWS instance where I save all my source files and someone suggested I install git and store versions and hence I did that with local git installation. I was checking files all fine and then due to one other suggestion that I need to have a copy on a remote server too, I started trying with bitbucket and added a remote server there and came to my AWS and did this in the top level directory

```
git remote add origin <the https url for the bitbucket repo>
git push -u origin master
```

Then for each subfolder I did as

```
git add <subfolder>
git commit subfolder -m "comments"
git push -v -u origin subfolder
```

The subfolders which themselves were not under git [means no .git in their folder], nicely copied and the subfolders which are under local git just have a name representation under remote repo with a number next to it
say as
HighwayHelp [c3ac266be9cb]

where highwayhelp is the subfoldername

When I try to push I get this error

```
error: src refspec HighwayHelp does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to <remote-https-link>
```

Whatever I try, I am not able to push these subfolders :-( 
As I said I am a novice in Git [I used to be an expert user of Clearcase] and I don't understand what I am doing wrong and worse I don't know how to fix this inspite of reading and trying everything I saw under stackoverflow

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

> *Then for each subfolder I did*
>
> ```
> git add <subfolder>
> git commit <subfolder> -m "comments"
> git push -v -u origin <subfolder>
> ```
>
> *The subfolders which themselves were not under git [means no .git in their folder]*

I think you have a misunderstanding about how Git works. A `.git` directory indicates a repository in that folder *and all sub folders*. When you added and pushed them you added and pushed them all to your one repository.

Let's walk through what happened...

- `git add <subfolder>`

This tells git to both track the files and to copy them to the staging area. The staging area is where Git builds up the next commit. The staging area is powerful, but takes some getting used to.

- `git commit <subfolder> -m "comments"`

This adds and commits the contents of `<subfolder>`. Since you specified what you wanted to commit it makes your previous `git add` redundant.

Either way, your subfolder is now committed to your *one* repository.

- `git push -v -u origin <subfolder>`

> *When I try to push I get this error*
>
> ```
>  error: src refspec HighwayHelp does not match any.
>  error: failed to push some refs to <remote-https-link>
> ```

This doesn't push just the changes in the subfolder, you can't do that. You can only push whole commits.

The syntax of `git push` is `git push <remote> <refspec>` where `refspec` is usually a branch to push both from and to. `git push origin HighwayHelp` says to push the branch `HighwayHelp` which does not exist. You can read up [more about refspecs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec).

Instead, since everything is in a single repository, and you've already committed them, you can simply `git push`.

---

If your subfolders represent separate projects, create new Git repositories for them. Don't store them as subfolders of a larger Git project, that's a great way to get confused. Give each project its own directory and its own folder.

If you do so, you'll want to remove those subfolder commits from your repository. Fortunately this is easy in Git. Do a `git log` to find the commit before you committed the subfolders and then `git reset --hard <that commit>`. This will move your branch back to that commit.

Comment: Thanks!! I think I better so separate repositories for different main subfolders. Thank you again